# How to fix a continous loop?

Tags: java, while-loop, infinite-loop

I am trying to loop the user input for flavour and number of scoops until when asked 'more ice cream purchased?' the user enters 'n' but when entering 'n' it displays the report and then asks for a flavour again? How can I stop this?

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

  int index = 0;
    {
      System.out.println("What flavour was chosen (strawberry, vanilla, chocolate) or type 'end' to finish?");
      iceCreamCone[0] = in.nextLine();

      System.out.println("How many scoops of this flavour?");
      iceCreamCone[0] = in.nextLine();
      index = index + 1;

      char choice;
      System.out.println("More ice cream purchased (y/n):");
      {
        choice = in.next().charAt(0);
        while (choice == 'y') 
        {
          System.out.println("What flavour was chosen (strawberry, vanilla, chocolate) or type 'end' to finish?");
          iceCreamCone[1] = in.nextLine();
          in.nextLine();

          System.out.println("How many scoops of this flavour?");
          iceCreamCone[1] = in.nextLine();
          index = index + 1;
        }
        if (choice == 'n') {
        {
          System.out.println("Report for today: \nTotal ice cream cones sold: \nTotal sales from the customers: ");

        }
      }
    }
    }
  }
```

Comment: you could use "break" to get out of a loop.. But where is your loop???

Comment: Use a simple `while(expression == true)` loop.

Comment: Parsing Posted Code : Beep: Error: Some code missing

Comment: I can't see a for(), while() or do while() in the code. If the code is surrounded by a loop the keyword break will break out of the loop and continue execution outside of the loop.

Comment: And there is duplicated code that isn't needed

Comment: My head compiler just went kind of crazy.

Comment: `while (choice == 'y')` you're never changing `choice` inside that loop, is that your actual code?

Comment: I am quite new to Java and am a little unsure of loops. I have used a while loop but what would I put after the while choice == 'y' if I do not duplicate the code? Sorry for probably what is a really stupid question.

Answer (score 0):

do something like this:

char y;

```
do
{


sop(which flavour);
sop(how many scoops);

System.out.println("wnat to enter more (y/n)");
Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in); or any stream class
read(ch)
}
while(ch=='y');
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing is that you have the same code twice in this program:

```
System.out.println("What flavour was chosen (strawberry, vanilla, chocolate)
or type 'end' to finish?");
  iceCreamCone[0] = in.nextLine();

  System.out.println("How many scoops of this flavour?");
  iceCreamCone[0] = in.nextLine();
  index = index + 1;
```

Put this in a method and call the method instead of calling it twice. Also change `iceCreamCone[0]` into `iceCreamCone[index]` thus your not always overwriting your second entry in the list.

Second problem is your loop which seems to never end.
Put

```
System.out.println("More ice cream purchased (y/n):");
choice = in.next().charAt(0);
```

into the while loop to the end. This way you ask in the while loop if no more scoops are bought.

Answer (score 0):

you are going in infinite loop if user first time ask for more ice cream. you need to ask user every time after he tell the scoops.

```
  char choice;
  System.out.println("More ice cream purchased (y/n):");
  {
    choice = in.next().charAt(0);
    while (choice == 'y') 
    {
      System.out.println("What flavour was chosen (strawberry, vanilla, chocolate) or type 'end' to finish?");
      iceCreamCone[1] = in.nextLine();
      in.nextLine();

      System.out.println("How many scoops of this flavour?");
      iceCreamCone[1] = in.nextLine();
      index = index + 1;

      System.out.println("More ice cream purchased (y/n)");
      choice = in.next().charAt(0);
    }

      System.out.println("Report for today: \nTotal ice cream cones sold: \nTotal sales from the customers: ");

    }
```